# Running rake task on ubuntu startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rake

Hi I'm having a bit of trouble with setting up a rake task to run on startup/reboot of a ubuntu instance on Amazon EC2.

I need to make my instance start a simple delayed jobs "rake jobs:work" command when a new instance is launched, without me having to login using ssh, and run the command manually. The problem is - I can't get it to execute the command. It works fine from terminal, but not by it self on startup. I have tried to follow the instructions in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43863/how-to-perform-a-rake-task-after-startup), but nothing seems to work.

I'm on a Natty 11.04 instance and I have installed ruby and gems through rvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to call something in a bash script that looks like this:

```
su - deploy -c "cd $RAILS_ROOT && rake RAILS_ENV=development jobs:work" >> $RAILS_ROOT/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Then call it from from your /etc/init.d/mystartup_filename. The file could look something like:

```
#! /bin/sh
RAILS_ROOT="/home/deploy/rails_root"
ENV="development"

case "$1" in
    start)
    echo -n "Starting my job: "
    su - deploy -c "cd $RAILS_ROOT && rake RAILS_ENV=$ENV jobs:work" >> $RAILS_ROOT/log/myjob.log 2>&1
    echo "done."
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Stopping my job: "
    su - deploy -c "cd $RAILS_ROOT && rake RAILS_ENV=$ENV jobs:stopwork" >> $RAILS_ROOT/log/myjob.log 2>&1
    echo "done."
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Okay nice answer - but I'm not too good at this ubuntu stuff - should the file have a specific type ending .something? And am I going to run any specific code to make the file run - or is it just enough to create a file in the directory init.d?

Comment: Okay I got it! using this http://tips4linux.com/create-a-startup-script-for-debian-and-ubuntu-systems/ and together with your post! Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: BTW I have noticed that when i run a "ps -ef" I see 3 processes running after applying the script: 
ubuntu     843   842  0 23:46 ?        00:00:00 su - ubuntu -c cd /home/ubuntu/webprojects/autouncle && rake RAILS_ENV=production jo
ubuntu     856   843  0 23:46 ?        00:00:00 -su -c cd /home/ubuntu/webprojects/autouncle && rake RAILS_ENV=production jobs:work
ubuntu     953   856 10 23:46 ?        00:00:18 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.
Does this make any sense???

Comment: Were there 0 processes running before? I believe delayed_job can have several workers. The default is 1, but you can start multiple instances and will start a separate process for each worker. Your task could be spawning 3 workers somehow.

Comment: I had to setup my ubuntu instance from scratch again and now I can't get the script to run - the only message in the log is: "-su: rake: command not found" any idea? if I just run the exact same command from within the directory itself - it works. As mentioned before i'm using RVM - but i read that it should still be able to wrap around "cd"...

Comment: 'rake' is probably not in the path. Try specifying the full path name.